# ExtJS+Selenium: @value gives nothing

Tags: extjs, selenium

I am using read only form and loading it in the controller using

```
"popup.down('form').loadRecord(record);"
```

Form fields are defined as

```
items:[
{
  xtype:'textfield',
  fieldLabel:'Array Id',
  name:'id'
},
{
  xtype:'textfield',
  fieldLabel:'Array Name',
  name:'name'
}
]
```

values : `[ id:10, name: 'testing']`

The generated HTML code is:

```
<form id = 'arraydevicewindowid'>

  <input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="x-form-field x-form-text" size="20"     name="${array.arrayName}" id="ext-gen1314" readonly="" aria-readonly="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="--NA--" role="textbox" aria-describedby="textfield-1260-errorEl" aria-required="false" data-errorqtip="" style="width: 281px; height: 23px;">

</form>
```

I tried to use the following xpath to select value from a textfield component generated by Extjs:

```
(//div[@id='arraydevicewindowid']//input)[1]//@value
```

But no luck.

```
(//div[@id='arraydevicewindowid']//input)[1]
```

can let me select the textfield I want, but `@value` doesn't work.

Any idea?

Comment: Which Selenium do you use, exactly? Selenium IDE (the Firefox plugin), Selenium RC (the old and deprecated one, but still usable), or Selenium WebDriver (the new and shiny one which uses WebDrivers all over the place)?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Selenium can't work with XPaths returning anything other than an HTML element. But the `value` attribute ... is an attribute of a node and the XPath essentially returns a String. Therefore, you have to select the right element and then get its value using Selenium in-built methods.

Using Selenium IDE: Some sort of magic with [`storeValue`](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0.1/reference.html#storeValue).

Using Java + Selenium RC:

```
// assuming 'selenium' is a healthy instance of Selenium
String value = selenium.getValue("xpath=yourXpath");
```

Using Java + Selenium WebDriver:

```
// assuming 'driver' is a healthy instance of WebDriver
String value = driver.findElement(By.xpath('yourXpath')).getAttribute("value");
```